# TFS 2010 lost but database intact. Can we resume using it?

Tags: sql-server, tfs, recovery, data-recovery

We lost a server with TFS2010 installed on it. Can we recover the source control as the database was unaffected on another server?

Comment: The answer is either yes or no.  Either way, you're going to try.  Not sure what value this question brings?

Comment: Because it's not as simple as just restoring a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumption: Your application tier was hosed, your database was not.

If that is the case, here's the text from the administation guide:

If you are using Network Service as the service account for Team Foundation (TFSService), on the application-tier server, open a Command Prompt window, and change directories to

```
Drive:%Program Files%\ Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Tools.
```

At the command prompt, type the following command:

```
TfsConfig Accounts /add /account:"NT Authority\Network Service" /SQLInstance:ServerName /DatabaseName:DatabaseName
```

**Note** 
For more information, see Accounts Command.

Install Team Foundation Server on the new server, and start the Application-Tier Only wizard.

For more information and step-by-step procedures, see Checklist: Adding an Application Tier, or download the most recent version of the installation guide for Team Foundation, and follow the instructions for how to use the Application-Tier Only wizard: Installation Guide for Team Foundation.

If you are using Visual Studio Lab Management, install the System Center Virtual Machine Manager (SCVMM) Administrator Console on the application tier, and configure it to connect to the server that is running SCVMM.

For more information, see Configuring Lab Management for the First Time.

If the computer name has changed, open the administration console for Team Foundation.

In the navigation bar, click Application Tier, and then click Change URLs.

The Change URLs window opens.

In Notification URL, type the URL for the new application-tier server, and then click OK.

**Note** 
The name of the old application-tier server will still appear in the list of application-tier servers in the administration console for Team Foundation. If you select the Filter out machines that have not connected in more than 3 days check box, the old server will disappear from the list within three days.

Answer (score -2):

Read [Administration Guide for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Team Foundation Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8175)

Comment: Link-only answers are frowned upon on Stack Overflow, since links tend to die out over time and answers are intended to be useful on their own, in the absence of any links. Ideally, you'd post the relevant parts of the documentation within your answer itself.

Comment: Well it's appropriate here.  I'm not going to attempt to _describe_ the recovery process, as it's fully documented and it would extremely dangerous to have a inaccurate understanding of the procedure.

Comment: Sorry @DavidBrowne-Microsoft it's a bloody AWFUL answer. All you just did was tell the OP to basically RTFM. How's that he;ping the OP at all? If that was the point of Stack Overflow then questions would be easy to answer....

Comment: And if OP incorrectly follows forum advice and looses her source repo?

Comment: Yes I did. OP's question _strongly indicated_ that the M had not been R'd, so I spent 10 minutes finding the exact right M for that old version of TFS and linked it.